# Disable the entry field of the Pmw.ComboBox widget

Tags: python, user-interface, combobox, tkinter

I am looking for a way to disable the direct editing of the `Pmw.ComboBox` widget. Widget configuration using the `entry_field=DISABLED` results with a grayed out and unusable ComboBox. Here is my code, which allows for direct editing of the menu:

```
        dropdownQOS = Pmw.ComboBox(parentWindow,
            label_text = 'QOS: ',
            labelpos = 'w',
            selectioncommand = differentiateSettings,
            scrolledlist_items = ("Selection1", "Selection2", "Selection3"), 
            listheight = 57,  entry_width = 43)
        dropdownQOS.selectitem(0, setentry = 1)
        dropdownQOS.pack(anchor = 'n',fill = 'x', expand = 1, padx = 50, pady=5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this page: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/63351
`entryfield_entry_state=DISABLED` worked for me too to disable the combobox' entry.

Comment: Thanks, configuring the ComboBox entry state with `entry_field=DISABLED` does the exact same thing, but additionally fixates the entry_bg to gray without allowing for further changes to background color. Not a deal breaker though.

Comment: I tried your code with `entryfield_entry_state=DISABLED`, `entry_field=DISABLED` and both of them with `'readoly'` parameter instead of `DISABLED`. The ComboBox worked and it's entry field was uneditable. Only the colors of the entry field was different in the 4 cases. If your ComboBox doesn't dorp down that means it is disabled from elswhere. (Or there is chance that we don't use the same versions of python, tkinter or Pmw. I use Py3.3, Tk8.5, Pmw2.0.)

Comment: Great, setting `entry_field` to `'readonly'` accomplished exactly what I was looking for; disabling the option of editing the entry but not graying out the field entirely (compared to using `DISABLED`). Thank you for your time!